# Dynamic content using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I came across the example below to dynamically change the shape and size of an object.

It's not a real live example but once I get it right, I'll apply it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
${"div").css("position","relative");
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").mouseenter(function(){
    var div=$("div");
    div.animate({height:'300px',opacity:'0.4'},"slow");
    div.animate({width:'300px',opacity:'0.8'},"slow");
    div.animate({height:'100px',opacity:'0.4'},"slow");
    div.animate({width:'100px',opacity:'0.8'},"slow");
  });
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The paragraph tag says that I need to set CSS positioning first to create dynamic contents - how do I do that? Is it also possible to have all components be enabled for dynamicity when created?

Comment: Don't you mean: `$("div").css("position", "relative");` with a `(` not a `{`. Here is a JSFiddle to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/rzFzd/1/. This works.

Comment: Yes I noticed the type but changing that didn't help either...

Comment: Got it, Thank you Mr. Polywhirl.

Comment: Just curious, the code works with no issues on jsfiddle but not on any of the web browsers on my local computer, what could be wrong?

Comment: you may not be using a webserver, and just opening the html file with your browser.. thats a really bad way to develop and causes many problems

Comment: what webserver do i use? you are right i am running the file from my web browser

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle with your animation working: http://jsfiddle.net/rzFzd/1.

If the jQuery isn't loading properly, it is because your web service may be confused with your script tags.

Change this:

```html
<script>
```

to this:

```html
<script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

You do not need to specify the `type` if you are using a browser capable of HTML5.